# Spring cloud sleuth 2.x custom trace id

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm currently working on a spring webflux project using Spring cloud sleuth dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm working on a set of APIs which get a request payload that contains 3 Strings. I want to concatenate these 3 strings to use as my custom trace id. I also want to achieve the following requirement.

1. This **custom_trace_id** should be able to be added to every log. (We are getting sleuth trace id in logs by adding `%X{traceId}` within our log4j.xml file to print the **traceId** in all logs)
2. This custom trace id must be sent to the calls that are made by WebClient (Sleuth sets the X-B3-TraceId header to all calls made by WebClient, I want the same but using the **custom_trace_id**)
3. If possible I want to change the name of X-B3-TraceId header to a different value such as **correlation-id** so that if someone makes a request to our spring webflux application the sleuth should first check the **correlation-id** and use it as trace id. (Note: custom_trace_id = correlation-id)

Note that the spring sleuth already does the above 3 things. I want to have custom value for the trace id instead. Can someone please help or suggest something for my usecase

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 2.5.x is not compatible with Spring Cloud Hoxton (Sleuth 2.2.x).
You need to use Spring Cloud 2020.0.x aka Ilford (Sleuth 3.0.x).

You can set `spring.sleuth.propagation.type` to `CUSTOM` and implement your own `Propagation` and `Propagation.Factory`, please see the docs: [How to Change The Context Propagation Mechanism?](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#how-to-change-context-propagation).

This should help you achieving your goals above, however, there are some downsides. This is mostly my opinion, please feel free to ignore it and do whatever you would like to:

- B3, W3C and AWS propagation types are standards with support of other projects/tooling
- You are trying to create a 4th "standard" that is not supported by anything (but maybe by an internal system)
- You need to add support for this custom propagation type to every new component so that they will also understand this "standard"
- Sometimes it worth consider moving to a universal standard rather than using a custom one even if there is a legacy system behind it

Comment: Hi Jonatan. Sleuth 2.2.8 is working fine. The reason for not using Sleuth 3.x is that I am facing the following issue while starting the spring boot application. `Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:
    org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.HttpClientBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(HttpClientBeanPostProcessor.java:76)

The following method did not exist: reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient.mapConnect(Ljava/util/function/Function;)Lreactor/netty/http/client/HttpClient;`

Comment: Trust me, they are not compatible but based on the error you get, I have a feeling that your dependencies are not in pace properly. Please do not define versions but use the spring boot and spring cloud BOMs.

Comment: For Sleuth how do I get dependency management(managed version)? Since it is not managed by `spring-boot-starter-parent` right

Comment: You can find in the docs:
https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies

Th Spring Boot Parent is for maven if you want to use it as a parent pom if you are not using maven or don't want to use the parent pom: 
https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies

Comment: I'm using Maven and Following your advice I'm letting the `spring-boot-starter-parent` choose dependency version for me. I'm using 2.3.3.RELEASE of spring-boot-starter-parent which changed my spring webflux version to 2.3.3.RELEASE as well. Seems like Sleuth 3 is not supported for it as my reactor-netty is 0.9.11.RELEASE version. Can you please tell me what can I do?

Comment: Use compatible versions: Boot 2.3 -> Hoxton (Sleuth 2.2.x), Boot 2.4/2.5 -> 2020.0.x aka Ilford (Sleuth 3.0.x) see our compatibility Matrix: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud#adding-spring-cloud-to-an-existing-spring-boot-application
If I were you, I would upgrade, btw Boot 2.6 was released last week and Cloud 2021.0.0 aka Jubilee (Sleuth 3.1.x) should be released at the end of this month.

Comment: Spring 2.4 and above don't have a RELEASE version `spring-boot-starter-parent` yet. I'm working on a application to make it to Prod, so that is why I'm using the 2.3.3.RELEASE version. Can you please send a link for modifying sleuth (version 2.2.8) trace id. (Also, FYI I want to have different trace id calculated depending on the request)

Comment: Nothing has or will have above 2.4. Whatever you find in maven central is stable, Boot left the `-RELEASE` modifier a long time ago. :)

Comment: I've already give you the docs (see y answer), from there with minimal effort you can navigate to older versons: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/2.2.8.RELEASE/reference/html/